# Creating Custom SharePoint Document Libraries/Lists using VSeWSS 1.3

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to create custom Document Libraries and Lists using VS2005/VS2008 SharePoint templates,i.e. VSeWSS 1.2/VSeWSS 1.3.

For example,I want to create a custom List based on the Calendar template but I also need to add some extra fields(columns) to it.

Can anyone tell me how to do this or refer me links to step by step tutorials/articles on how to develop since I was unable to find any useful references.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Best way IMHO is to copy already existing List Template and edit it as you want it. For your case you can make a copy of **C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\EventsList** and call it **CustomEventList** and do the changes you want.

You can get started [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/02/08/A-Quicker-Way-to-Create-Custom-SharePoint-List-Templates.aspx) and [here](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/create-custom-list-definitions-in-caml/).